# Managed builds on Linux

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse, tfs, eclipse-cdt

We have a TFS server which runs builds of our Windows-based software.
Now we had to port part of our software to Linux and we want to run the builds in a similar manner on Linux.
The project on Linux is created using Eclipse CDT, written in C++. The question would be how to run builds of this project on a Linux machine, and will it be possible to somehow integrate it into TFS infrastructure? For quality control, etc.

Answer (score 0):

There is no out-of-the-box solution: currently there are no agents for Linux.

But wait, I did this once for a customer. The solution's pieces were:

1. setup SSH on Linux
2. write a Linux build script and save it in TFS version control
3. modify the custom template using the Community Build Extensions to:
   a. push the script 
   b. invoke the script remotely
   c. collect the build log(s)
   d. copy the logs to the OutDir

I wrote a blog post with detailed instruction: http://casavian.eu/wordpress/2014/02/13/integrating-linux-builds-in-tfs/.